# Can women go to stonings?

Tags: halacha, women, capital-punishment

In Monty Python's The Life of Brian, it is asserted that women can't go to stonings because "it is written".

Are women allowed to attend stonings? What about throwing stones?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15742/759

Comment: I'm uncertain if the verse in Bamidbar 15:36, which says that "ALL the congregation" (Heb. "Kol Ha'edah") that stoned the Shabbat violator included women that were involved in the stoning. None of the commentaries I see there mention anything either way.

Comment: @DanF See the mishna ([*Sanhedrin* 45a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=45&format=text)): רגימתו בכל ישראל שנאמר יד העדים תהיה בו בראשונה להמיתו ויד כל העם באחרונה. It does not limit it to men.

Comment: See שיירי קרבן (*Sanhedrin* 6:4) who seems to suggest that ונוסרו כל הנשים ([Ezekiel 23:48](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1223.htm#48)), which requires women to attend the sotah ritual ([*Sotah* 8b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=8b&format=text)), extends to executions as well.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Fred's reference to Sanhedrin 45a, the answer would be not only are women not forbidden from attending a stoning, but they are involved in the stoning process itself!

Comment: Actually, I just found [this remark](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50375&st=&pgnum=192) by R' [Yitzchok Sorotzkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Sorotzkin), who says צריך עיון regarding whether this includes women.

Comment: @Fred - Actually, YOU should have posted the answer, not me ;-) The fact that I "stole your thunder" in itself, צריך עיון ;-)